# Dudas con ley de demeter

Tags: java, pseudocódigo

Tengo el siguiente diagrama de clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despúes tengo este pseudocodigo en java donde se ve claramente que la clase "customer" en la función getTotalCost() no se cumple la ley de demeter...

```
public class Customer 
{
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private Boolean subscribed;
  private ReasonType reasonUnsubscribed;
  private List<Move> moves;
  
  public Real getTotalCost() 
  {
    Real total = 0;
    foreach (Move m in moves) 
    {
      List<Item> items = m.getItems();
      foreach (Item i in items)
      {
        total += i.getPrice();
      }
      Company c = m.getCompany();
      total += m.getDistance() * c.getPriceKM();
      if(typeof(m)==MultipleDayMove) {
        Integer extraDays = m.getEndDate() - m.getStartDate();
        total += extraDays * m.getExtraPerDay();
      }
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

Mi duda es como deberíamos cambiar las clases para que este método de customer cumpla la ley de demeter.

Las otras clases implicadas están así:

Clase Item

```
public class Item
{
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private ItemType itemType;
  private Real price;
  private Boolean assembly
  public Real getPrice()
  {
    return price;
  }
}
```

Y por ultimo la clase Company

```
public class Company
{
  private String taxID;
  private String name;
  private Real priceKM;
  private Real operatorCommission;
  private List<Operator> operators;
  private List<Move> moves;
  public Real getPriceKM()
  {
    return priceKM;
  }
}
```

La ley de demeter no se cumple en getTotalCost de Customer, debo de modificar algo en las clases para que se cumpla,

Comment: Pues por lo visto no se ve tan claramente como crees. ¿Qué problema has tenido para modificarlo?¿Qué has intentado?¿Qué has investigado?¿Con qué punto de la definición de la Law of Demeter tiene problema tu solución?

Comment: Pues haber, la Ley de Demeter digamos que es una buena practica de diseño y uno debe aproximarse a esta lo mas que se pueda. En esencia una clase debe cumplir con dos principios: alta cohesion y bajo acoplamiento. Alta cohesion porque la clase debe ser capaz de resolver solamente los problemas para los que fue creada y bajo acoplamiento porque debe ser lo menos dependiente posible de otras clases.

Comment: @RuslanLópez se supone que en el metodo getTotalCost() de la clase costumer,la ley de demeter no se cumple ya que uso dentro de la funcion objetos de clases que no estan relacionadas con customer,como por ejemplo la creacion del objeto company y creo que tambien con la clase item,ya que no estan relacionadas directamente con customer.Segun entiendo,para la ley de demeter indica que el metodo de una clase de comunicarse con objetos de la propia clase,objeto creado por la funcion ,objeto pasado como argumento al metodo y un objeto en una variable instancia de la clase.¿Como lo soluciono?

Comment: @Japv,eso es,eso lo tengo claro y por eso creo que la funcion getTotalCost no la cumple,ya que habla con objetos e invoca a metodos de clases con las que no esta directamente relacionada,mi pregunta es,que puedo cambiar en el metodo y en las clases para que se pueda cumplir la ley...Pensé en meter el metodo getTotalCost() de Customer en Move que si que está relacionado con Company,Item y MultipleDayMove

Comment: ¿La clase Real se supone que fuera un double?

Comment: @RuslanLópez si, efectivamente, sería un double .Realmente lo que quiero es hacer una modificación en la cual el método getTotalCost de la clase Customer cumpla de la ley de demeter, osea que no hable con desconocidos...Se me ocurre poner el método en la clase Move y hacer esa abstracta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, lo que se aprecia con tu diseño es que la clase `MultipleDayMove` está fuertemente acoplada, lo mismo sucede con `Item`.

Un primer buen principio es que generalmente si hallamos un `instance of` deberemos desconfiar de nuestros mecanismos de herencia, esto será lo primero que corrijamos.

```
public class MultipleDayMove extends Move {

    private Date endDate;

    private double extraPerDay;

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public double getExtraPerDay() {
        return extraPerDay;
    }

    @Override
    public double getCostPerExtraDays() {
        double costPerExtraDays = 0;
        LocalDate instance = endDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate instance1 = startDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        Long extraDays = DAYS.between(instance, instance1);
        costPerExtraDays += extraDays * extraPerDay;

        return costPerExtraDays;
    }

}
```

Posteriormente llevamos los cálculos a la clase directamente responsable que es `Move`.

```
public class Move {

    protected Date startDate;
    private double distance;

    private List<Item> items;
    private Company company;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public double getCostPerExtraDays() {
        return 0;
    }

    public double getDistanceCost() {
        return distance * company.getPriceKM();
    }

    public double sumItems() {
        double itemSum = 0;
        for (Item i : items) {
            itemSum += i.getPrice();
        }
        return itemSum;
    }
}
```

Y ahora nuestra clase Customer quedará con las ventajas que se mencionan en el [artículo original de la Ley de Demeter](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/papers/law-of-demeter/oopsla88-law-of-demeter.pdf):

- Las modificaciones que se hagan a futuro serán más simples de realizar
- Simplifica la complejidad del programa al hacer que el programador tenga menos entidades que tomar en cuenta

  ```
  public class Customer {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Boolean subscribed;
    private ReasonType reasonUnsubscribed;
    private List<Move> moves;

    public double getTotalCost() {
        double total = 0;

        for (Move m : moves) {
            total += m.sumItems();
            total += m.getDistanceCost();
            total += m.getCostPerExtraDays();
        }
        return total;
    }

  }
  ```

Comment: Esto es justamente a lo que me referia,ahora la el metodo getTotalCost queda mucho mas limpio y si modifico cosas en las otras clases no le afectará.Muchas gracias por la explicacion,ahora lo veo mucho más claro sinceramente